# Checking if entity exist before saving it to core data swift4.

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to add data to Core Data in my application. When I save it without checking if it already exists it works fine. But I don't what duplicates in my core data so what I do I fetch all the entities with the name of entity im trying to add first and then check if it's 0 I add it else no. But I'm keep getting an error when trying to save. If anyone could help  me with the problem.

This is my checking function:

```
func entityExists(name: String) -> Bool {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "name")
    fetchRequest.includesSubentities = false

    var entitiesCount = 0

    do {
        entitiesCount = try coreDataController.mainContext.count(for:         fetchRequest)
    }
    catch {
        print("error executing fetch request: \(error)")
    }

    if entitiesCount == 0{
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

This is my code when I save the data.

```
if entityExists(name: (scrimmagePassedOver?.name)!) == true{

    coreDataController.saveContext()
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "You have saved your Scrimmage.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

   // add an action (button)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
   } else {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "hey", message: "You have saved this Scrimmage before.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
   self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: You probably mean *Checking if **entry*** – or record – *exists before saving it to core data*. The Core Data *entity* is required to exist.

Comment: Yes that is what i mean

Comment: You have to fetch the record with the specific search criteria. If it does not exist, save it.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: that is the error: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: noo sorry this is the error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSFetchRequest could not locate an NSEntityDescription for entity name 'name''

Comment: Do you have an entity `name` in your model?

Comment: I know this is a little old, but looking at your code, shouldn't it read ```if entitiesCount == 0 { return false } else { return true }``` since you are checking to see if the entity exists a value of 0 would mean it does not exist, right?  Am I reading this wrong?

Comment: Or use `return entitiesCount != 0`

Answer (score 2):

You can check the record from your core data like that:

```
func checkRecordExists(entity: String,uniqueIdentity: String,idAttributeName:String) -> Bool {
    let context = getManagedObjectContext()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: entity)
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(idAttributeName) CONTAINS[cd] %@", createdDate)

    var results: [NSManagedObject] = []

    do {
        results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    }
    catch {
        print("error executing fetch request: \(error)")
    }

    return results.count > 0

}
```

and `managedObjectContext` is:

```
func getManagedObjectContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext{

    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

    return delegate!.persistentContainer.viewContext
}
```

If you get `false` then save it.